# Terminal "rails generate controller pages home" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I'm following a course online and used the following command in terminal to generate a homepage:

```
rails generate controller pages home
```

Following this terminal stopped responding and I had to use C^ to exit. When I do this the following text is displayed:

```
^C/Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:99:in `gets': Interrupt
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:99:in `verify_server_version'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:56:in `run'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:37:in `warm_run'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:26:in `call'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/askinakhan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/askinakhan/Desktop/pinteresting/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I don't have a clue what's going on. Here's what i'm running in my app:

- ruby 2.2.0p0
- rails 4.2.0

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks
Ash

Comment: Try to remove the GemFile.lock then run `bundle install` and maybe a `bundle update`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ludovic but this didn't work

Comment: Try to comment in your Gemfile : gem 'spring' then do the previous moves again.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much Ludovic! Although, won't this cause problems in the future if I come to use the gem spring? Is there no permanent fix?

Comment: It's sounds like a bad installation of "Spring". Maybe you should install it again by cleaning all gem. Could you post your gemfile ?

Comment: Sorry i've been on holiday. Below is my gemfile...

    source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'

group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :production do 
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end

Comment: Where is the spring line ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success either looking for the running spring process and killing it (`ps aux | grep spring`) or running `bin/spring stop`.

What happened with my particular case is that I had a folder with an app, moved it and didn't stop the server (which kept spring running I believe). So spring was still pointing to the old folder. Hope it helps.